# tesseract multithreading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, tesseract

I have a code for tesseract to run in 1 instance how can i parallelize the code so that it can run in quad core processor or 8 core processor systems.here is my code block.thanks in advance.

```
  using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "tel+tel1", EngineMode.Default))
        {

            foreach (string ab in files)
            {
                using (var pages = Pix.LoadFromFile(ab))
                {
                    using (Tesseract.Page page = engine.Process(pages,Tesseract.PageSegMode.SingleBlock))
                    {
                        string text = page.GetText();
                        OCRedText.Append(text);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: First thing to find out is if `TesseractEngine` supports concurrent calls to `Process`

Comment: yes iam sure it will ts enhancement in 3.02 is support multi thread..

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Ocr(string directory, string sep)
    => Directory.GetFiles(directory, sep)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(x =>
        {
            using var engine = new TesseractEngine(tessdata, "eng", EngineMode.Default);
            using var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(x);
            using var page = engine.Process(img);
            return page.GetText();
        }).ToList();
```

I am no expert on the matter of parallelization, but this function ocr's 8 Tiff's in 12 seconds.

However, it creates an Engine for every Tiff. I have not been able to call engine.Process concurrently.

EDIT: There are even more ways to do this:

0. Define a Type to contain OCR Results:

```
public record Text(string Value);
```

1. Define an asynchronous OCR Method:

```cs
static async Task<Text> OcrAsync(byte[] fileContents)
{
    using var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"\pathTo\tessdata", "deu");
    using var pix = Pix.LoadFromMemory(fileContents);
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var text = engine.Process(pix);
        return new Text(text.GetText());
    });
}
```

2. Define a Method that consumes OcrAsync in Parallel. We make use of [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-7.0)

```cs
static async Task ParallelOcrAsync(IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> fileContents)
{
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(fileContents, async (f, g) =>
    {
        await OcrAsync(f);
        Console.WriteLine($"{f.Length} bytes Ocr'd");
    });
}
```

You can easily extend this to fill a parallel-friendly collection (e.g. [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-7.0))

This yielded good results for me.
Tesseract 5 + Parallel => 100 Tiffs in 88 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to run this code in parallel is using [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx). Calling *AsParallel()* on enumeration will automatically run query that follows it (*.Select(...)*) simultaneously on all available CPU cores.

It is crucial to run in parallel only thread-safe code. Assuming TesseractEngine is thread-safe (as you suggest in comment, I didn't verify it myself) as well as Pix.LoadFromFile(), then the only problematic part could be *OCRedText.Append()*. It is not clear from code, what OCRedText is, so I assume it is StringBuilder or List and therefore it is not thread-safe. So I removed this part from code that will run in parallel and I process it later in single-thread - since method *.Append()* is likely to run fast, this shouldn't have significant adverse effect on overall performance.

```
using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "tel+tel1", EngineMode.Default))
{
    var texts = files.AsParallel().Select(ab =>
            {
                using (var pages = Pix.LoadFromFile(ab))
                {
                    using (Tesseract.Page page = engine.Process(pages, eract.PageSegMode.SingleBlock))
                    {
                        return page.GetText();
                    }
                }
            });

    foreach (string text in texts)
    {
        OCRedText.Append(text);
    }
}
```